# Django: Loop through all attributes of a OneToOneField inside the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to loop through all the related attributes of a OneToOneField inside a Django template but it gives an `'PropertyFeatures' object is not iterable` error. This list of features is going to grow considerably and rendering them out individually with their own `{% if %}` statement is not a good idea. Is it possible to loop through `OneToOneField` attributes inside the template?

## Models

```
class PropertyFeatures(models.Model):
    property = models.OneToOneField(Property, related_name="features", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_pet_friendly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_garden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

## Views

```
def property_detailview(request, pk):
    template_name = "property/detail.html"

    property = Property.objects.get(id=pk)

    context = {
        "property": property,
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

## Template

```
{% block content %}
    {% include "includes/navigation/navbar.html" %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            {{ property.title }}
        </h1>
        <div>
            {{ property.features.has_garden }} <-- This works
            {% for feature in property.features %} <-- This gives an error
                {{ feature }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
  
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

OneToOne, as its name suggests, is a single object. It's not iterable. There isn't any built-in method for iterating over attributes of a model. You might write one:

```
class PropertyFeatures(models.Model):
...

@property  # a Python language feature
def feature_list(self):
    return [ self.is_pet_friendly, self.has_garden ] # add to  as necessary


{% for feature in property.features.feature_list %}
```

(In passing, is this the right design? One might instead have a model `Feature` with a ForeignKey or ManyToMany relationship with `Property`, which would be interable with `property.features.all` ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, a ManyToMany relationship makes more sense here